# How did my users upload a profile photo in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, backend, photo

How would a user in my Wordpress site upload a user photo if they don't have access to the backend, or if there is no front-end upload mechanism?

I suddenly saw some of my users with pictures in the admin backend user list. How did they do that?

Comment: See this link your solution [How to change profile picture in wordpress?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105801/how-to-change-profile-picture-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WordPress uses [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) service to display user’s profile picture. Users profile picture is based on your email address. If users do not have a [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) account then your profile picture will be replaced with a default image placeholder which is called “Mystery Man”. this is how user can set their gravatar picture.

- Visit [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) website.
- Sign in to Gravatar with your WordPress.com account. If you don’t
  have a WordPress.com account then you need to create one.
- Upload your avatar (profile picture).

Comment: Will look into this one. Can I check if my user has a gravatar account?